# Remove unused properties from application.properties in maven project. How to validate that removed property is unused one

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am working on very big project that is built in maven. How to remove unused properties from application.properties and how that can i validate that i remove the correct unused property.

Comment: Remove them step by step and run all your tests (unit- and integration tests)...

Comment: @khmarbaise actually there are 7 microservices and each property line is upto 400 .

Comment: So what? Why have you added so many properties in your application? Does everyone  know what purpose they have? Apart from that you haven't wrote how many you have ... 400 ? Do you mean you have 400 different properties set in your application.properties (I assume this is a spring boot app?) So you are overwriting every existing property in spring boot ... ?Why? Simplest start remove all of them... add only really things which are necessary...